# can my devices work well on a usb hub?

Tags: usb, laptop, streaming, gaming, usb-hub

I'm planning on buying a usb hub and I'm wondering if my devices will even work well on it.

My laptop is Asus Zephyrus gx501vik , it has four USB3.0 ports and one thunderbolt 3 port ( I assume its thunderbolt because of the thunder symbol next to it ).

My main usage is gaming and now also streaming sooo.... 4 ports is definitely not enough.... I found this usb hub in Amazon and it seems to have some decent reviews ( I hope it's fine to post amazon links here - if not then its Anker 10 port 60w usb hub ) : [https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B00VDVCQ84/ref=ox_sc_act_image_8?smid=A294P4X9EWVXLJ&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VDVCQ84)

if you have anything better I would love to know!

these are the devices I'm planning on plugging in (not specifically to the hub, but overall to the laptop):

1. usb ethernet adapter ( to connect directly )
2. logitech g900 mouse wireless receiver
3. steelseries arctis 7 wireless receiver
4. focusrite scarlett solo audio interface
5. logitech c930e web camera
6. razer huntsman elite keyboard

I also need 3 ports for power only to recharge my headphones/mouse when needed and connect my cooling (cooler master sf-17), but that's less of the problem here.

the usb hub is powered but I'm still afraid about the actual performance, from what I know a USB3.0 port can provide up to 5GBps ( unsure if that's still true in  a laptop, correct me if I'm wrong ) but I am unaware of how much each of those devices will require and will the devices even perform correctly or with a massive delay ( wouldn't want a weird delay for my web cam or audio interface while streaming, or even worst to my keyboard or mouse ).

I have to note that I currently only own the mouse and the headphones, I'm planning on buying the others once I fix my port problem. so let me know if anything else might pose a problem ( or generally a bad idea to buy or connect to a USB hub )

thank you very much for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well when gaming and streaming latency is key.. especially in fast pace fps games where players will buy peripherals based on things like how low the polling or Hertz rate is..

Ultimately no matter how fast the controller on the hub is, it is adding additional distance for the signals to travel which will inevitably increase latency. If only slightly but that increase will be there. 
And the more devices you plug into the hub the more signals the processor controller has to process which inevitably will slow things down. Im sure that if it is high quality you probably wouldnt notice though.

Personally I think Id go down the route of plugging the keyboard and mouse directly into the laptop to make sure the distance the signals have to travel is the shortest it can be plus not adding another level of processing should be beneficial as every millisecond can count toward getting a shot off first and suriving in game or dying.

Same reason players with 144hz monitors still want to push extreme framerates above 144 fps.. as NVIDIA like to point out, every frame counts and apparently higher frame correlates to higher K/d.

Although I will admit that could be because people who buy expensive high end equipment to field high FPS are more likely to be hardcore gamers and just better but that's beside the point lol..
Anyway imho the same principle applies to your peripherals.

I know with the webcams I've tested with hubs they can be a bit slow and cause latency issues but the additional bandwidth Thunderbolt 3 has might eliminate that.

I had a quick look on asus's website and it states that you've got a thunderbolt 3.0 port over USB C.. just confirm that before buying anything though but I'd say if you can find a hub that connects through the thunderbolt but has USB connections that's probably a better option than USB as USB 3 has a maximum bandwidth of 5 GB per second 3.1 is up to 10 and Thunderbolt is 40 gigabits per second...

So for e.g. if you have a USB 3 hub with four USB 3 ports, each port is sharing the overall bandwidth of the USB plug going back to the computer. 
So one device operating at its max theoretical speed might potentially be able to saturate the 5 gigabit connection and get full speed but if you plug in four devices then they are sharing that bandwidth And only get 1.25 GBs each.. where as in the same situation but connected by a Thunderbolt 3 which has the 40 gigabit per second speed, each USB 3 device will easily be able to operate at it maximum speed of 5gbs. I this case you would need eight USB 3 devices to fully saturate the connection.

Anyway, here's a thunderbolt over USB C hub I found with a quick Google search and even includes ethernet..
https://www.amazon.com.au/Thunderbolt-Adapter-Multi-Port-Charging-Ethernet/dp/B073VYX5C1

Hope that helps a bit and good luck getting it all sorted..

Comment: Also sorry just noticed that particular hub on Amazon is out of stock but I'm sure you can find another one lol