# do i own thunderbolt 3 port and is there a large usb hub for it?

Tags: usb, laptop, gaming, thunderbolt

i own a Asus Zephyrus GX501VIK with four USB3.0 ports and one type C port i cannot figure out what it is.

Asus's site claims its a "USB 3.1 Gen2 Type-C over Thunderbolt™" which frankly i have no idea if its USB3.1 or Thunderbolt 3.
I will say that i do have the intel thunderbolt program installed on my laptop (didn't install it so i guess it came with it).

The reason i need to know is mainly because of my last post : [can my devices work well on a usb hub?](https://superuser.com/questions/1446814/can-my-devices-work-well-on-a-usb-hub)

which made me realize connecting through USB3.0 is not enough.

so basically those are my questions:

1. USB 3.1 Gen2 Type-C over Thunderbolt™ means thunderbolt 3? if not what is it? will it provide 40GBps as well?
2. i tried searching for a thunderbolt 3 USB hub and i literally couldn't find anything with enough USB ports, i basically need only 6+ USB ports working through thunderbolt 3 - don't need ethernet or hdmi or w/e all the hubs have.

Hope you can help me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Asus's site claims its a "USB 3.1 Gen2 Type-C over Thunderbolt™" which frankly i have no idea if its USB3.1 or Thunderbolt 3. I will say that i do have the intel thunderbolt program installed on my laptop (didn't install it so i guess it came with it).

It's Thunderbolt 3.

> I tried searching for a Thunderbolt 3 USB hub and I literally couldn't find anything with enough USB ports, I basically need only 6+ USB ports working through thunderbolt 3 - don't need ethernet or HDMI or w/e all the hubs have.

Thunderbolt 3 devices support being daisy-chained.  there is also a maximum amount of 6 devices that can be connected.  **Thunderbolt 3 devices are NOT USB devices.**  In your other question, you did not list a single Thunderbolt 3 device, all of the devices were USB 3.2 Gen 1 devices.  **`USB 3.2 Gen 1` is the current name for USB 3.0**

> USB 3.1 Gen2 Type-C over Thunderbolt™ means thunderbolt 3? if not what is it? will it provide 40GBps as well?

This means your device has a single Thunderbolt 3 port.  You can confirm this by the lighting bolt logo near the port itself.

> Thunderbolt 3 re-uses the USB-C connector from USB.

The difference between a USB 3.2 Gen 2 Type-C port and a Thunderbolt 3 (Type-C) port is significant.  **Thunderbolt 3 combines Thunderbolt, USB, DisplayPort, and power via a single USB-C connector.**

Source: [What is Thunderbolt 3? What is the difference between USB-C and Thunderbolt 3? What Thunderbolt 3 adapters and docks are available?](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-touch-bar-faq/what-is-thunderbolt-3-difference-between-thunderbolt-3-usb-c.html)

> Thunderbolt controllers multiplex one or more individual data lanes
>   from connected PCIe and DisplayPort devices for transmission via two
>   duplex Thunderbolt lanes, then de-multiplex them for use by PCIe and
>   DisplayPort devices on the other end.  A single Thunderbolt port
>   supports up to six Thunderbolt devices via hubs or daisy chains; as
>   many of these as the host has DP sources may be Thunderbolt monitors.

Source: [Thunderbolt (interface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)#Thunderbolt_3)

> "I only wish to use thunderbolt's bandwidth to enjoy more regular USB3.0 ports" -

**This is not possible.**  You will not gain access to Thunderbolt 3 bandwidth by connecting a USB Hub to a Thunderbolt 3 port.

> is it not possible to buy a USB hub that connects via Thunderbolt and connect my regular USB3.0 devices into the hub?

Based on my research Thunderbolt 3 is compatible with USB 3.1 Gen 1.  This means you can connect a USB 3.1 Gen 1 Hub to a Thunderbolt 3 port.  However, you are limited by the bandwidth of USB 3.1 Gen 1 in the process.

> does it mean the 6 devices limit still apply?

The 6 device limit only applies to Thunderbolt 3 devices.

> so i can only buy a 6 port hub like this?

The port in question converts a single Thunderbolt 3 port into 6 USB 3.0 Gen 1 ports.  The devices you listed were all USB 3.0 devices and a single USB Hub should be able to support them.  The combined bandwidth requirements can be supported by a single USB controller.  **You will not gain anything by using your single Thunderbolt 3 port instead of one of your USB 3.0 ports.**